# Validate a form before submit in Vue3 composition api with vuelidate

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuelidate

[According to documentation](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/guide.html#validating-forms-before-submitting)  example there is the following Vue.js options api way to validate the whole form before submitting it

```
export default {
  methods: {
    async submitForm () {
      const isFormCorrect = await this.v$.$validate()
      // you can show some extra alert to the user or just leave the each field to show it's `$errors`.
      if (!isFormCorrect) return
      // actually submit form
    }
  }
}
```

I am using Vue.js 3 with composition api and simply can't make this work in my case.

In my `<template>` i have a form

```
<form
  @submit="submitHandler"
>
  <input>
    :error="v$.productName.$invalid && v$.productName.$dirty"
    @input="v$.productName.$touch()"
  </input>
  
  <input>
    :error="v$.productPrice.$invalid && v$.productPrice.$dirty"
    @update:model-value="v$.productPrice.$touch()"
  </input>

  ...
</form>
```

Under `<script setup>` tag i have the following

```
import { useVuelidate } from '@vuelidate/core'
import { required, integer, minValue } from '@vuelidate/validators'
...
const state = reactive({
  productName: '',
  productPrice: '',
  
  ...
})

const rules = {
  productName: { required, $lazy: true },
  productPrice: { required, integer, minValue: minValue(1), $lazy: true },
  
  ...
  $validationGroups: {
    allProductData: [
      'productName',
      'productPrice' ,
      
      ...
    ]
  }
}

const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, state)

...

const submitHandler = async () => {
  try {
    const isFormCorrect = await v$.$validate()
    console.log('Submit Fired')
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn({error})
  }
}
```

`submitHandler()` gives me an error saying `error: TypeError: v$.$validate is not a function`. I tried with and without making it `async` and got the same error.
I also tried to place the same code directly in the `<form>` `@click` event handler and it works perfectly fine.

```
<form
  @submit="v$.validate()"
>
...
</form>
```

Am i missing something ? It seems to me like vuelidate2 `v$.methodName()` only works in the template which is strange because i recall using it exactly as documentation suggests in my Vue.js 2 applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`useVuelidate` returns a ref](https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/blob/%40vuelidate/core%402.0.0/packages/vuelidate/index.d.ts#L184-L192), this is not well-documented but can be expected from a reactive composable.

Refs are automatically unwrapped in a template, in a script it's supposed to be:

```
const isFormCorrect = await unref(v$).$validate()
```